# Sorting Dictionaries Specific Keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was recently scraping Hacker News website specifically (Titles, Links, Votes) and here's the code the code for that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

titles = soup.select('.storylink')
subtext = soup.select('.subtext')


def custom_hn(titles, subtext):
    with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for i, item in enumerate(titles):
            title = titles[i].getText()
            link = titles[i].get('href', None)
            vote = subtext[i].select('.score')
            if len(vote):
                points = vote[0].getText().replace(' points', '')
            else:
                points = '0'
            my_dict = {'Title': title, 'Link': link, 'Votes': points}
```

My complaint is that how do I go about sorting Votes so that it writes in result.txt in reversed order along with its relevant info such as its title, link.

Comment: You could use `sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x["Votes"])`

Comment: Thanks @bigbounty, I tried that but it gives the typeerror: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

titles = soup.select('.storylink')
subtext = soup.select('.subtext')


def custom_hn(titles, subtext):
    data = []
    for i, item in enumerate(titles):
        title = titles[i].getText()
        link = titles[i].get('href', None)
        vote = subtext[i].select('.score')
        if len(vote):
            points = vote[0].getText().replace(' points', '')
        else:
            points = '0'
        data.append({'Title': title, 'Link': link, 'Votes': points})
    
    newlist = sorted(data, key=lambda k: int(k['Votes']))
    
    with open('result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(newlist, f)
```

For sorting in reverse order,
Change the sorted line to
`newlist = sorted(data, key=lambda k: int(k['Votes']), reverse=True)`

Comment: Hey @bigbounty how do I format the result.txt file in a way that it writes newlist into it while also giving space after each set of Info like for each title.